# Create-react-app 2.1.1: Sass doesn't really load

Tags: typescript, sass, create-react-app

I have a small application running with *react-scripts-ts* (3.1.0) and *node-sass* (4.10.0) added.

When I import say *"./App.scss"* no import error is shown - but no styles are being added. Neither importing as a module or importing regularly works.

- If I try to import a file that doesn't work *create-react-app* throws an error.
- If I try to import a regular css file, the styles are applied regularly.

Any ideas? :\

---

Package.json dump:

```
{
  "name": "reason-md-webapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@veracity/ui-react": "0.2.66396",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "node-sass": "4.10.0",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "0.31.5",
    "react-dom": "16.6.3",
    "react-redux": "5.1.1",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "0.24.4",
    "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "5.0.0-alpha.8",
    "react-scripts-ts": "3.1.0",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts-ts start",
    "build": "react-scripts-ts build",
    "test": "react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts-ts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/enzyme": "3.1.6",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.0.1",
    "@types/jest": "23.3.9",
    "@types/node": "10.12.6",
    "@types/react": "16.7.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.0.9",
    "@types/react-redux": "6.0.9",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "@types/redux-logger": "3.0.5",
    "enzyme": "3.2.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.1.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "3.3.0",
    "prettier": "1.15.2",
    "react-router-test-context": "0.1.0",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "1.16.0",
    "typescript": "3.1.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Having the same issue with `react-scripts-ts`, any new causes? It also doesn't throw an error, but does not seem to import or compile scss files, but css works...

Comment: Yes. The react-scripts-ts package was to blame for the issue. I ended up using the regular react-scripts package since it now contains typescript support - and then the issues went away.

Comment: same here, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the *react-scripts-ts*. I ended up using the regular *react-scripts* package since it now contains typescript support - and then the issues went away.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to follow these instructions from official documentation. Try to reproduce this step by step:
[CRA DOCS](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet#docsNav)

First install node-sass and make sure it's saved in your project dependencies than rename App.css to App.scss and include it into your index.js entry point JavaScript file. Sometimes you need to play with index.css file - remove it and make sure to remove all imports to this file from other .js files.

Comment: No luck. I have tried to remove my lock files, remove the node_modules folder. Remove node_sass and re-add it. Run with admin rights. Run without.

It's the exact same as if I have chosen to do: *import "./randomstaticfile.weirdextension";* Nothing happens as long as the file exists.